# Typecasting from pointers to uint32

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, int, linker-scripts

Iam going through a linker descriptor file and found following lines of code and I am unable to understand the typecasting concept used here.

```
extern std::uintptr_t   __sROData_LMA[]; /* start of LOAD region for DATA */
uint32_t * p_src, * p_dest;
#ifdef XMC_BOOT
    // Copy the rodata segment initializers from ROM to RAM.
    // Note that all data segments are aligned by 4.
    p_src  = static_cast<uint32_t *>(static_cast<void*>(__sROData_LMA));
    p_dest = static_cast<uint32_t *>(static_cast<void*>(__sROData));
    while (p_dest < static_cast<uint32_t*>(static_cast<void*>(__eROData)))
    {
        *p_dest++ = *p_src++;
    }
#endif
```

What does the line `p_src  = static_cast<uint32_t *>(static_cast<void*>(__sROData_LMA));`meant in the program? How is typecasting being done here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wrong language. This is C++, not C.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, yeah it is cpp

Comment: The cast converts the uintptr_t into something that can be used to copy the contents from ROM to RAM. To find out why it first casts to `void*` try removing the `static_cast<void*>` and read the compiler error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, that you cannot dereference a void pointer, but a uint32_t pointer.
The code itself is used for `Copy the rodata segment initializers from ROM to RAM.`, which is afaik required for ELF binaries.
In fact, this is a [`mempcy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy).

Comment: How is it different than just casting directly to `uint32_t*` using a `reinterpret_cast`? Why is it necessary to go through `void*`?

Comment: In this case `reinterpret_cast` is equivalent to two static casts as in the code abovce (IRC, it's defined as this in such cases), but with static_casts it's much harder to make a mistake 9i.e. if you change some types in the future). While reinterpret_cast will cast anything to anything (almost) without any warning. Just the matter of style. Prefer `static_cast` to other casts.

Comment: @user8540390 I may need the full source code to answer that question, e.g. what type is  `__sROData` and `__eROData`